# Telerik Grid GridColumnSettings issue

Tags: telerik-mvc

How can I do following the right way:
Assign column template to the column in GridColumnSettings
What I mean:

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid. .. .Columns(c => c.Bound(t.Name).Template(tp => Html.ActionLink...
```

works fine

but, when I create ColumnSetting in codebehind, and pass it to view,

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid ... Columns(c => c.LoadSettings(Model.Columns))
```

That I've notice that there are not Template property in GridColumnSetting class
 So, how can I assign Template to the column, if column setting is passed from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported because you cannot access the Response Write method of the View in the Controller - it is available only in the View (this Method is used internally by the Grid to write its output). This is the reason why there is not Template method in the Grid column settings.